# How do i prove $\omega\times\omega\approx \omega$, **not using prime decomposition nor division**?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Yet there are many ways to prove this, i remember that i saw a proof in a text which proves this without using any decomposition nor division. (I remember the name of the text is "Set theory - Pinter", but i lost this text long time ago and i'm home now)

How do i prove this not using decomposition nor division?

Comment: If you write $\omega$ instead of $\aleph_0$, you're indicating that you want to view it as an ordinal rather than a cardinal, and with ordinal multiplication $\omega\times\omega\neq \omega$.

Comment: Do you mean Cantor's pairing function: $$f(n,m)=\frac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}2+n$$

Comment: @Henning: Note that $\approx$ symbol, rather than $=$.

Comment: @Henning You are right that is customary, but i meant cardinal multiplication. I'll edit it.

Comment: @Asaf No. I remember there is a proof in the text not using *division*. (Since $n$ is finite, ordinal or cardinal multiplications are identical here. No ambiguity)

Comment: @Asaf If one wants to say *a finite ordinal is divisble by two* one must first define what the multiplication is, but i clearly remember that, in that argument, one doesn't need to know that.

Comment: @John: Instead of saying "divisible by two" you could say "is $x+x$ for some $x$". You don't need to define multiplication for that. That said, I doubt you can define an injection $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ without either using multiplication or defining something very much like multiplication-with-the-serial-numbers-filed-off along the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard "Cantor zig-zag" bijection $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ is something like
$$ f(x,y) = x+\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2} $$
No division (except for a halving) or factoring used here.

Its inverse needs a square root and a bit of footwork, though.

---

If you want to avoid the halving but can accept a definition by cases, how about
$$ g(x,y) = \begin{cases}x^2+y & \text{if }x>y \\ y^2 + 2y - x & \text{if }y\ge x\end{cases}$$

---

Even more alternatively, consider the injections
$$ h(x) = (x,x) \qquad\qquad k(x,y) = 10^{2x}+10^{2y+1} $$
and appeal to the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem.

Comment: Just replace $\frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}$ with $\sum_{i=1}^{x+y} i$.  Then _really_ no division! ;-)